# Laravel crear una "migration" con foreignkeys

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7

He creado una instalación de laravely he instalado passport , al hacer lo se han creado los modelos de user entre otros , ahora tengo unos modelos mios que se llama "Aliments" donde tendré un campo user_id referenciado al campo id de la tabla users.

Para ello tengo esto en la migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('diets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->integer('type');
        $table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
        ...

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Pues el error que me da es este

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `portal`.`#sql-2c6c_d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `diets` add constraint `1` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

Answer (score 1):

Cuando crees una Foreign Key que haga referencia a un numero incremental, acompáñalo siempre de `unsigned()`.

`$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();`

Y claramente, asegurate de que la Foreign Key sea creada despues de que se cree la tabla a la que haga referencia.

Comment: Al ponerle unsigned me da este error ahora.

 `  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `portal`.`#sql-2c6c_14` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `diets` a
dd constraint `diets_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))`

Comment: Veo que habla de una tabla llamada portal, asegurate que pones `unsigned()` en todas las tablas donde declaras una columna que hace referencia al id de otra. ¿La tabla users, el id es integer o bigInt? Prueba cambiando user_id a integer